# react-dates onDatesChange startDate and endDate are null, DayPickerRangeController

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-dates

This is `DayPickerRangeController` component from `react-dates`:

```
 <DayPickerRangeController
                    startDate={dates.startDate}
                    endDate={dates.endDate} 
                    onDatesChange={onDatesChange} 
                    focusedInput={focusedInput} 
                    onFocusChange={focusedInput => setFocusedInput(focusedInput)}
                    numberOfMonths={2} 
                />
```

I am using a functional component and the default state is:

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState({ startDate: null, endDate: null });
const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState(null);
```

This is changeDates function:

```
const onDatesChange = (dates) => {
    //setDates({ startDate, endDate });
    console.log(dates);
}
```

, but on dates change, the result is this: `{startDate: null, endDate: null}`

I can change the default date to invaling string like so:

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState({ startDate: 'jkhjkhjk', endDate: null });
```

and the result on bind the change event `{startDate: "jkhjkhjk", endDate: null}`

with the warning for invalid value for a date

Comment: works for me [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dates-date-range-picker-forked-18dtg)

Comment: Thanks, but u are using `DateRangePicker`, The question is for `DayPickerRangeController`. You can see it here from your edited example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dates-date-range-picker-forked-554vw?file=/src/date-picker.jsx:85-100

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the docs are unclear about `DayPickerRangeController` and the reqired prop `focusedInput`:

[image]

It must be `startDate` and not `null`:

```
const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState('startDate');
```

or from constants:

```
 import { START_DATE, END_DATE } from 'react-dates/constants';
 ...
 const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState(START_DATE);
```

and be sure that is not `null`, like after selecting `endDate`:

```
focusedInput={focusedInput || START_DATE} // startDate
```

Working demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dates-date-range-picker-forked-e8qne?file=/src/date-picker.jsx

Comment: If you are using typescript, use the `FocusedInputShape` type for it from `@types/react-dates` package